# Removal of a repeated syllable for ease of pronunciation

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, linguistics

What do you call the removal of a repeated syllable in words for ease of pronunciation?

I read about it once. I think it has to do with alliterative sounds. Not sure if it was deliberate or not.

Comment: Can you supply an example of such a word, and its shortened form?

Comment: With words like *library* or *Leicester*, whole syllables might be skipped. But these aren't examples of words with *repeated* syllables.

Comment: @Lawrence - Your comment makes me think that _Worcestershire_ may be a good example (apparently, this isn't confined to purely repeated syllables).

Comment: @Lawrence: What syllables are skipped in the normal adult pronouciation of library?  As for Leicester &c, were they ever pronounced as they are spelled?

Comment: @jamesqf, it's not uncommon to hear 'library' pronounced as "LYE-bree'

Comment: @jamesqf Some pronounce [*library*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/library) with 2 syllables (middle syllable skipped), some with 3. See IPA at the foot of the linked page. I looked around regarding Leicester - see [this link](http://www.freethought-forum.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-747.html), Darren's entry at time stamp "06-25-2005, 11:19 AM", something about it starting off as *Legacaster*.

Comment: @Lawrence: IDK about lots of people - I'm only familiar with the kids' "lye-berry".  WRT Leicester &c, I was wondering whether it's not a relic of different spelling conventions, as with Irish/Scottish words, e.g  "Dun Laoghaire" = "Dun Leery".  Consistent if you know the rules, utterly confusing to someone who knows only standard English spelling.

Comment: @jamesqf The kids’ pronunciation doesn’t drop a whole syllable, though. It is said that English spelling is fairly consistent ... so long as you take into account the language each word came from. :)

Answer (score 24):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haplology) says:

> **Haplology** (from Greek ἁπλόος *haplóos* "simple" and λόγος *lógos*, "speech") is defined as the **elimination of a syllable when two identical or similar syllables occur consecutively**. The phenomenon was identified by American philologist Maurice Bloomfield in the 20th century. Linguists sometimes jokingly refer to the phenomenon as "haplogy".

The Wikipedia article lists a handful of examples, including:

- *probly* (colloquial for *probably*)
- *urine analysis* > *urinalysis*

Now, if you'd excuse me, my grandson is asking for a "bana".